# Dual diode connection for return path

Tags: diodes, fuses, circuit-protection

I want to use the following [dual diode](https://www.mouser.jp/ProductDetail/747-DSA50C100QB) for the return path with a fuse.

The diode is dual with each diode rated 25A, the cathode is the same, which means I have to connect it like in the figure? Do I have to add something more?

**EDIT 1**

The purpose is to protect a motor controller as explained in [this datasheet](http://downloads.ionmc.com/docs/roboclaw_datasheet_2x30A.pdf), pp 10.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2filbj2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Putting two diodes in parallel is not normally recommended, though it won't hurt anything here; just know that almost all the current is going to go through one of the two diodes and make sure it's rated for that. You could just connect one of the diodes and leave the other pin floating, if you prefer, or use it for some other purpose.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Is the fuse intended be in parallel with the diodes?

Comment: Yes, I want to put a safety circuit for my motor controller, the vendor says you have to put a fuse in parallel with a diode, but I cannot find a diode that covers the requirements. 12V and 40A. I updated the question with the info.

Comment: Where do you get the figure of 40A from?

Comment: I am using two motors of 20 amps each, so the battery will supply 40 amps.

Comment: The diode is not there to handle the 40A supply current from the battery (it's reverse biased so it won't conduct). It's there to handle regenerated current from the motors in the event that the fuse blows. So how do you calculate that as 40A?

Comment: Mmm, I didn’t, I assumed it had to be as high as the current provided. I guess that is wrong, right?

Comment: Okay, so the peak current might be as high as the maximum current, but not for long. I think you'll want to look at single pulse current limits.

Comment: Diodes will normally handle peak currents of 10 times their rated continuous forward current with no problem. I'm sure you can find a single diode that will do the job.

Comment: You can assume a ONE TIME PULSE (1/60 second or 1/120th second) that is 10X the nominal rating. The thermal mass of the silicon and of the metal in the packaging will absorb that heat. Then you must allow the entire HOT mass to cool down.